# How to get child element inserted in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a buffer:

```
var buff="<div id='main'><p id='foo'>Hello World</p></div>"; 
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.innerHTML = buff; 
// Don't document.write mydiv, but do the operation below
mydiv.getElementById("foo").innerText = "Hi there!";
```

It's not currently not working, what should I do?

Comment: `mydiv` doesn't have a `getElementById()` method.

Comment: I got an error in the console for that line, didn't you?

Comment: mydiv.querySelector("#foo")

Comment: There's no point in scoping "getElementById" because ID's are all unique in a document

Comment: @user120242 you are a life save, thank you very much!

Comment: @user120242 you may put that on answer, and I'll accept it

Comment: @chris alright, answer added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `getElementById` per element because IDs are all unique.  You use `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` for element scoped queries, or `document.getElementById` to search the document by ID

You can use either
`mydiv.querySelector('#foo')`
or
`document.getElementById('foo')`

Answer (score 0):

object `mydiv` don't have property function getElementById.
[image: property of object mydiv]

You need create `buff` variable like this:

```
var buff="<div id='main'><p id='foo' class='bar'>Hello World</p></div>";
```

then change inner text of `foo` by:

```
mydiv.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].innerText = "Hi there!"
```

Hope this help!